# How did the Romans remove graffiti?

Tags: ancient-rome, crime

There is plenty of evidence that people painted or etched [graffiti in Ancient Rome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_graffiti).

I was curious whether and how the authorities removed the graffiti, did they paint over it or wash it off (and presumably paint back the original color)?

Especially with the etches, I can't imagine that would have been easy to remove. I couldn't find any sources in my search though I might not have been looking thorough enough.

Comment: What makes you think they removed the graffiti?

Comment: [Obligatory Monty Python reference](https://goo.gl/images/FpPtLE)....

Comment: @Semaphore J. A. Baird and Claire Taylor, in their "Ancient Graffiti in Context", talk about 'layers of graffiti' (p. 8), which indicates that even if there was no systematic removal of graffiti they could be painted over from time to time.

Comment: @JamesCook Yes, surely repainting has been carried out since the invention of painting buildings. I think these were usually private, e.g. by the owners, though. So I am wondering if there's evidence of the government systematically trying to remove graffiti, whether by painting or otherwise.

Comment: @Semaphore Ah yeah you make some good points, I was just imagining in my head some insulting graffiti of a high ranking official's wife etc. And them paying/ordering to have it removed.

Comment: @Semaphore There doesn't seem to be a systematic effort by the government to remove graffiti, but there was political propaganda (for the elections) and ads for gladiatorial shows that could be painted over existing inscriptions. So, in a sense, people connected to the government could erase some graffiti in order to paint other things over them, even though in a more general sense the government didn't care about graffiti.

Comment: It is likely an open question as to whether Roman culture considered graffiti to be vandalism.

Comment: @StevenBurnap I think they would have. They already had been complaining that the youth was getting worse generation by generation.

Comment: Pompeii furnishes us a few clues: (1) While there is evidence of professional message-painters, there are none of official white-washing campaigns; (2) graffiti often was painted over; (3) once revealed by archeologists, the ancient Roman graffiti eventually fades -- the paint used was not that durable!